# Why is my https URL redirected to http?

Tags: redirect, https

This is my https URL, it points to a controller in my custom module:

```
https://127.0.0.1/MyProject/index.php/test/index/logurl/
```

Now, in my module I tried to config that URL as secure, like this:

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <test>/index/logurl/</test>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

The frontName of my module is "test". Its just not working, when I call the URL, it always ends at:

```
http://127.0.0.1/MyProject/index.php/test/index/logurl/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <test_index>/test/index</test_index>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Your module's frontend name is `test`. Hence you need to specify that in inside `secure_url` node

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel change secureUrl
System->configuration->General->web->SecureUrl

or
Refer this

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1792/magento-custom-module-frontend-url-is-forced-to-https-why/

```
<secure_url>
<mymodule>/mymodule/</mymodule>
</secure_url>
```